# Package to compare document semantic similarity (LSA, TF-IDF, Cosine Similarity, Language Models)

Tags: document, nlp, similarity

I'm looking for a package (any programming language) that I can use on a corpus of 50 documents to perform interdocument similarity testing using various metrics like term frequency-inverse document frequency ([TF-IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)), Okapi best matching ([Okapi-BM25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25)), [language models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model) (probability distributions over a sequence of words), [LSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis), etc.

As the result, I want a document similarity matrix (i.e. `doc1` is `x`% similar to `doc2` etc.). This is for research purposes, not for production. I specifically want the document similarity matrix as I want to correlate this with human ratings.

Answer (score 0):

If you know python, you can use http://www.nltk.org - it has everything you need, and plus is the documentation and the python language